# Multiple Windows opening for each methods Webdriver

Tags: webdriver

I was automating using webdriver but for every method I write, the root window disappears and a new window shows up thus breaking the previous flow. I am using Firefox. Kindly help me with this issue. I used one method for Login, then another for searching a particular record.

Answer (score 1):

Provide sample code of your methods. Which framework you are suing? If its TestNG check your driver object instance creation and tear down methods?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you instantiate the driver element many times.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); - maybe this line is duplicate somewhere
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```